# on Android mobile, React.js dropdown needs to tap twice to open

Tags: android, reactjs, dropdown, double-click, iscroll

using `React JS`, I Created a `Horizontal` navigation with 10 items. the fist item is a dropdown menu with 5 items.
I used `ReactIScroll` in order to scroll the Navigation horizontally on mobile devices.
when I open the module on Android mobile, the first time I click on the first item, which is a dropdown, it opens with one click. this is as expected.

the issue is: when I close the dropdown, and scroll Horizontal navigation all the way to right so that first item that is dropdown goes out of Mobile view, then I horizontally scroll to left to bring the first item into view: now, when I try to open dropdown, it needs 2 tap.
what causes this issue ?

why when I do Horizontally scroll to right and then to left, and then trying to open dropdown, it needs double tap?

note: it only need one tap at the beginning when I open the module on Android mobile.

Note: iPhone perform fine. no issue

It works fine on Desktop.
It works fine on iPhone & iPad.

Comment: I am having the same issue but only in firefox